# MS Access Filter

Tags: sql, ms-access, filter

Working with MS Access 2013 I have 3 tables:

```
tblTypes
 - Type
tblItems
 - ItemNumber
 - Item
 - Type
tblList
 - xDate
 - Type
 - Item
```

`tblItems.Type` is linked to `tblTypes.Type` as is `tblList.Type`. For `tblList.Item`, I am trying to come up with a query that filters only the items that are linked to that type.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT tblItems.Item
FROM tblList INNER JOIN tblItems ON tblList.Type = tblItems.Type
WHERE tblItems.Type = tblList.Type
```

I want to use this in the `tblList.Item` dropdown and only display the Items that are of the type specified by the `tblList.Type` on that same row.

[image]

Comment: Dropdown? What dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a specific type, you could do something extremely simple like this.

```
SELECT tblItems.Item
FROM tblList a
    INNER JOIN tblItems b ON a.type = b.type
WHERE b.type = "Name of type"
```

Comment: The "Name of type" will change depending on what the user selects for that row.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you may be looking for is setting a subdatasheet. In design mode for the table, open your properties pane and towards the bottom is "Subdatasheet Name". When selected, you can choose from the drop down the query you wrote to find the matching type.

Back in table view, you can click the "+" sign for the row to display the related records below the selected row.